# Magento multistore on different servers/hosts

Tags: php, magento

I would like to know if its possible to have different stores on different servers with a multistore configuration.

Following one of these tutorials

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/how-to-create-multiple-store-with-different-domain-in-magento

You can have different stores on different domains but they should point on the same machine, (I guess), as I receive this error:

```
http://secondarydomain.it/app/Mage.php was not found
```

To clarify I have **1 Magento install with 2 stores**

store1

store2

on **domain1/server1**

and

I would like to have again the **store2** on **domain2/server2**, and be able, as user, to buy and search products through store 2.

My question is: it is possible to have something like this or multistore just work on a single server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short answer is not possible.

In long it may be possible by sharing database. However you have to have Magento code in both servers.

The principle of Magento multi-store is to share same code-base, same-db which means have one server.

Comment: OK tnks. Any workaround/possible solution/different approach will be appreciated.